# When using the "start debugging" option, it says that .exe has triggered a breakpoint. I don't find any breakpoints in it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, executable, breakpoints

I have a visual studio 2012 project. Actually, It was built in Visual studio 2010 and now I'm working on it in VS 2012. I did all the things required to convert it to 2012. The problem is that when using the "start debugging" option, it says  that .exe has triggered a breakpoint. I don't find  any breakpoints in it. To the best of my knowledge, I removed all the breakpoints.

Anyone knows the solution to this ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "Clear All Breakpoints" and rebuilding?

Comment: Actually, since there is not a "clear all breakpoints" option in Debug menu when it comes to 2012, I used the shortcut ctrl+shift+F9. And then, cleaned it. After cleaning, built it. It's still the same

Comment: Your code could be calling `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`.

Comment: What is the *exact wording* of the error message you are getting?

Comment: I edited the question with the screenshot of it